# Auto layout of vertical panels in Delphi

Tags: delphi, layout, vcl

I have been away from Delphi for a few years, doing web apps.

I have gotten used, in HTML of just declaring successive `<div> ... </div>` and having them placed below each other, with spacing provided by CSS.

I want to do a Delphi app where I have a collection of data, let's say it's data about movies. Initially, I would have a panel for each , showing only the title. If you click one, it will expand to show actors, director, plot summary, etc. Click another and the first will shrink & the new one expand (max one expanded; click that one again to shrnkk it).

So, I have two layout problems: 1) to calculate  the initial `.top` of each panel and 2) to re-calculate as different panels are clicked.

I am quite capable, of course, of coding all of this manually, but it seems tedious and error prone.

Is there an accepted way to do this? A VCL component that comes with Delphi? Should I be asking on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for a 3rd party VCL component?

Comment: A category panel group comes close. You can collapse all but the expanded category panel when one is clicked.

Comment: Thanks! (+1) Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: Done.. You're welcome.

Comment: As always, no explanation for the downvote :-(  Bring on the "me too"s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest VCL control is probably [`TCategoryPanelGroup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCategoryPanelGroup), which is composed of vertically aligned expandable panels ([`TCategoryPanel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCategoryPanel)).

The control does not have an 'autocollapsepanels' or 'maxexpandedpanelcount' property, but you can use some simple code to achieve the required behavior. 
E.g. the below `OnExpand` event handler, if attached to all category panels in the group, will cause an expanded panel to close others.

```
procedure TForm1.CategoryPanelExpand(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Sender is TCategoryPanel then
    for I := 0 to CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels.Count - 1 do
      if CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels[i] <> Sender then
        TCategoryPanel(CategoryPanelGroup1.Panels[i]).Collapse;
end;
```

You can set `AlignWithMargins` property of your panels to true, then adjust spacing by using the `Margins` properties of the panels.